# Is transcendental meditation pseudoscience?

Tags: meditation

Is transcendental meditation pseudoscience or it is confirmed by official medical science?
Does students learn it at study and does it realy helps to cure depression,panic,fear,anexity,some diseases ?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em3XplqnoF4

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Can you please elaborate within your question what you mean by **transcendental** meditation and how it differs from any other forms of meditation? What makes you think it may be pseudoscientific and therefore not able to provide the relaxation or anything else it is purported to be able to do?

Comment: @ChrisRogers I agree that help in relaxation,but does it realy cure depression,fear,anxiety,panic attack,disease etc?Is it proved in offical medical science?